# New Google Calendar landing page scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I'm trying to create a page similar to new google calendar landing page http://www.google.com/landing/calendar/

I'm using skrollr(https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) but I can't get the effect right, on google landing page if you do a small scroll it will send you to the next block and with skrollr I'm not able to get that navigation. Any ideas how I could reproduce that? is it possible to do with skrollr or you would recommend another js plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried what I proposed? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you still haven't found a solution yourself, I've been tasked with doing a very similar thing. There are two ways of achieving this that I researched and choosing the right one mostly depends on the complexity of your design/expected result. Unfortunately I can't provide a link because the site won't be live for next couple of weeks.

**This is what worked for me:**

I used [**fullpage.js**](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs) library to achieve 'full-page' scroll effect. You could also take a look at [**onepage-scroll.js**](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) and see which one fits you most - they don't differ that much in terms of functionality though.

**Benefits of using fullpage.js (among other things):**

- integration is quick and simple
- allows a lot of customisation through options hash
- provides callbacks when scroll to another section is triggered (before or after it happens)
- enables you to manually trigger a scroll via 'methods'
- works surprisingly good on iPad/iPhones. Probably on other mobile devices as well, although I can't fully confirm that since that
  wasn't a requirement for my project.

Now when you've got section-to-section scrolling in place, what's missing is the animations. **Considering that fullpage.js provides you with callbacks, it's as easy as adding a class when a transition to another section/slide happens and then using that class to trigger an animation of your choice through CSS.** This is what worked for me without facing major problems.

**For more advanced things:**

If you're looking to build something more complex, then I strongly recommend that you take a look at [**tween.js**](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/). This is what google used on the landing page that you've provided in your question.

It's a very powerful tool hence it requires quite some setup + it moves animations to javascript, which might be a hassle. I would rather keep them in CSS where they belong and dont use javascript until I really need to.

---

<s>*FYI I also started with skrollr but it won't really work with 'fullpage scroll' because what it really does is disabling scrolling and animating body/html through translate. Skrollr bases it's behaviour on scroll event which will not fire if you use libraries I proposed.*</s>

**EDIT:**
It appears that you can actually use skrollr in par with fullpage.js. You can see the answer on how in it's [FAQ site](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frecuently-Answered-Questions#how-can-i-set-fullscreen-videos--backgrounds). Thanks to [Alvaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081396/alvaro) for claryfing that! Even then, I wouldn't use skrollr unless you really need it for some advanced parallax scrolling effect - as said before, depends on your needs though. :)

Let me know if you have any doubts or something is not clear in my answer.

**Good luck!**

Comment: Just to clarify, Skrollr could work on fullPage.js when using the option `scrollBar:true` as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html). It is also explained in [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frecuently-Answered-Questions).

Comment: @Alvaro 
Thanks for clarifying that, I somehow managed to miss it... I've edited my original answer with this info. And thanks for your library, it saved me a lot of work!